# Looking for a customized filter webpart for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter

the filter webpart is too weak in sharepoint online.  I am looking for a customized filter webpart for sharepoint online.  I tried to find the vendors but they all can only run on server, not sharepoint online.  Do you know any vendors can provide advanced filter webpart for sharepoint online?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

thanks Benny,

http://www.sharepoint-webparts.net/ListFilterWebpart.aspx

something like this.  it has demo on it. you can try it out.  I am looking for company that can help me to create such webpart on sharepoint online.

Gary